# How to use two copy event on one page separately using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using 'copy' addEventListener for one page. And also on click of button, I am also using copy but the issue is when I use on click copy content then at the end by default copy event also fires. What I want when I use on click copy then that by default copy on that page should be removed or hide.

Below is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  const pagelink = `\n${document.getElementById('judgmentNameHighlight').value}`;
  event.clipboardData.setData('text', document.getSelection() + pagelink);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

this one is bydefault and

```
$("#btnCitationParenthesisCopy").click(function () {

    var judgmentNameHighlight = $("#judgmentNameHighlight").val();
    var courtName = $('#courtNameCustom').val();

    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var urlid = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'/getCitations',
        data:{urlid:urlid},
        success:function(data){
            
            var finaldata = `${judgmentNameHighlight}, ${data['ac']} ("These two appeals, one by the convict, ${data['res']} and the other by the ${data['pes']} are directed against one and the same judgment of the ${courtName} and were therefore heard together and are disposed of this common judgment.")`;
            $('#copyCitation').val(finaldata);

            var copyText = document.getElementById("copyCitation");
            copyText.select();

            copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
            document.execCommand("copy");

            // alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
        }
    });
});
```

When i copy anything from this code first code also run bydefault.

How should i remove bydefault copy event when use click copy event ??

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use global boolean flag and assign it in both event

Comment: ok Thanks can you please elaborate it will be easy to understand.

Comment: what should i change in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use.. i didn't check.

```
window.globalFlag = false;
```

in you click event call it

```
element.on('click', function() {

window.globalFlag = true;


// after ajax success and copy call it back
window.globalFlag = false;
});
```

in you copy event

```
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
   if (!window.globalFlag) {
     // do you staff here
   }
});
```

Comment: now my copy event not working. click is working fine.

Comment: after executing copy in your `click` event, try setting `window.globalFlag` to `false` again.

Comment: I just update my answer @firatozcevahir thanks I forgot to set variable back false.